# Ubuntu going from 2560x1440 to 1920x1080 makes everything super blurry on a 17 inch laptop monitor

Tags: display, display-resolution

I am using a 17 inch laptop monitor. The initial resolution of 2560x1440 is not blurry but when I change it to 1920x1080 everything becomes blurry. How do I fix this? I have used a 24 inch monitor on 1920x1080 and it does not get blurry so I dont believe that a 17 inch monitor would be blurry.

Comment: "I have used a 24 inch monitor on 1920x1080" .. were your eyes as close to the 24" monitor as it is to the 17" one?

Comment: @muru no, I know it is not supposed to be this blurry. How can I fix it? I have older computers with lousier resolutions and it is still not this blurry.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? Are you using X or Wayland?

Comment: @muru i am using Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2):

When using some resolution different from the intrinsic one, there will be interpolation and the screen will be blurry or pixelated.

- There are ways to change the settings of the software, for example Firefox to increase the fonts etc so that you get a good user experience at the intrinsic (and high) resolution.
- In Ubuntu 20.04.x LTS you can also change the whole Gnome desktop settings for this purpose. Click at the top right corner and

  - select Settings
  - select Displays
  - Try with different Scale settings (you may activate fractional scaling)
- An alternative that might look good is half of the intrinsic resolution, in your case (2560x1440)/2 = 1280x720. This corresponds to Scale "200%" in Gnome's settings-display menu.